# IBM Bluemix POST vs. GET for Image recognition. Is URL necessary in parameters.json file?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I seem to be unable to get a POST request to work for image recognition using the /classify API for IBM BlueMix.

The following curl works fine for GET:

```
curl -X GET -H "Accept-Language: en" "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?&api_key={api_key}&url={link to image}&classifier_ids=default&owners=IBM&threshold=0.2&version=2016-05-20"
```

It recognizes as a banana (correctly).

I can't seem to get it to work for POST.  Here is my URL:

```
curl -X POST -F "images_file=@IMG_0632.JPG" -F "parameters=@parameters.json" "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key={api_key}&version=2016-05-20"
```

My parameters.json is pretty simple:

```
{
      "classifier_ids": ["default"],
      "owners": ["IBM"],
      "threshold": 0.2
}
```

Also, the same image is used in the GET as in the POST.  I can get POST to work *if* I add the line below to parameters.json.
`"url": "{link to url here}"`

Question: Is it possible to get POST to work *without* using a URL and just uploading the image and form encoding the images_file?  If so, any hints on the POST formatting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem between a POST and a GET was different image resolution.  When I did a GET and uploaded the image to the postimage site, it somehow reduced the image size (even though it said it wouldn't).  With a POST the image size was unchanged.  Odd, but that is the only difference I can come up with is that the lower image resolution was easier for blue mix to recognize as a banana.